# googletest: is it possible to select a single test fixture/case?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I use [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer) for C++ unit testing. I have defined multiple classes deriving from `::testing::Test`, each of which has multiple test functions defined with `TEST_F`.

I run them all with

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

When debugging, I'd like to focus on a specific test case. Is it possible to run only a specific `Test` or `TEST_F`?

Comment: If you use Eclipse you can use breakpoints to pause execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the gtests command line option `--gtest_filter` wehen invoking the executable for the debugging session. @see [Running a Subset of the Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208148/1713859)